# parallel test with appium & selenium grid

Tags: android, selenium, parallel-processing, appium, selenium-grid2

I'm trying to run parallel test on 2 devices using appium & selenium grid but for some reason it runs only on the first node server (and first device) but nothing happen on the second server.

Also if I'm shutting down the first server and run the test then the test run on the second server so there shouldn't be any issue with the servers.

Is there some parameter that I have to give in order to set it to parallel ?

Thanks for the help !

Here are my files :

First server json file :

```
{
  "capabilities":
  [
    {
      "browserName": "SamsungS6",
      "deviceName": "04157df40862d02f",
      "version":"6.0.1",
      "maxInstances": 3,
      "platform":"ANDROID"
    }
  ],
  "configuration":
  {
    "cleanUpCycle":2000,
    "timeout":30000,
    "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
    "url":"http://localhost:4491/wd/hub",
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 4491,
    "maxSession": 5,
    "register": true,
    "registerCycle": 5000,
    "hubPort": 4433,
    "hubHost": "localhost"
   }
}
```

Second server json file :

```
{
  "capabilities":
  [
    {
      "browserName": "OnePlusOne",
      "deviceName": "14b2b276",
      "version":"6.0.1",
      "maxInstances": 3,
      "platform":"ANDROID",
      "platformName":"ANDROID"
    }
  ],
  "configuration":
  {
    "cleanUpCycle":2000,
    "timeout":30000,
    "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
    "url":"http://localhost:4490/wd/hub",
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 4490,
    "maxSession": 5,
    "register": true,
    "registerCycle": 5000,
    "hubPort": 4433,
    "hubHost": "localhost"
  }
}
```

Run the selenium grid :

```
java -jar selenium-server.jar -role hub -port 4433
```

Run first scenario

```
node.exe node_modules\appium\bin\appium.js --nodeconfig myfirstscenario.json -p 4490 -U 14b2b276 -bp 5490 --chromedriver-port 6490
```

Run second scenario

```
node.exe node_modules\appium\bin\appium.js --nodeconfig mysecondscenario.json -p 4491 -U 04157df40862d02f -bp 5491 --chromedriver-port 6491
```

The test

```
@BeforeTest(alwaysRun = true)
public void setUp(){

    try {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "ANDROID");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "");
        capabilities.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, appPackage);
        capabilities.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, appActivity);

        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4433/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Test
public void test(){
    System.out.println("hello world");

    try {
        sleep(6000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@AfterTest(alwaysRun = true)
public void closeDriver(){
    driver.quit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because neither have you provided anything that is unique in your DesiredCapabilities nor have you added a custom CapabilityMatcher. By default the Grid uses only the browserName, version and platform to decide which node a test is to be routed to.

Here's one way of fixing the problem. Add a new key named "applicationName" to your nodeConfig.json and set the values of "OnePlusOne" and "SamsungS6" respectively. You then add a new capability named "applicationName" to your desired capability in your test and then set the value of "OnePlusOne" and "SamsungS6" respectively. After this your test would be routed to the correct device.

You can read more about this in my blog post [here](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2014/01/19/working-with-a-custom-capability-matcher-in-the-grid/).

Answer (score 0):

i also faced the same issue but got resolved by

Step1: add the appium (.. \Appium\node_modules.bin) in you environment variable 
Step2: make the differen json for the each node.

for node 1

```
 {   "capabilities":
    [
      {
        "version":"6.0",
        "maxInstances": 1,
        "platform":"ANDROID",
        "newCommandTimeout":"30",
        "deviceReadyTimeout":5
      }
    ],   "configuration":   {
    "cleanUpCycle":2000,
    "timeout":10800,
    "url":"http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 4723,
    "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
    "maxSession": 1,
    "register": true,
    "registerCycle": 5000,
    "hubPort": 4444,
    "hubHost": "127.0.0.1"   } }
```

for node 2

```
 {
  "capabilities":
    [
      {
        "version":"5.0.2",
        "maxInstances": 1,
        "platform":"ANDROID",
        "newCommandTimeout":"30",
        "deviceReadyTimeout":5
      }
    ],
  "configuration":
  {
    "cleanUpCycle":2000,
    "timeout":10800,
    "url":"http://127.0.0.1:4733/wd/hub",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 4733,
    "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
    "maxSession": 1,
    "register": true,
    "registerCycle": 5000,
    "hubPort": 4444,
    "hubHost": "127.0.0.1"
  }
}
```

now for to run the hub i have made that in a batch file

```
java -jar %cd%\selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar -role hub http://127.0.0.1:4444/grid/console
```

and

for node1

```
appium -a 127.0.0.1 -p 4723 --no-reset --bootstrap-port 4728 -U 192.168.56.101:5555 --nodeconfig %cd%\5555appium1.json
```

and node 2

```
appium -a 127.0.0.1 -p 4733 --no-reset --bootstrap-port 4738 -U 4d00af03525c80a1 --nodeconfig %cd%\4d00appium2.json
```

and in you code add the deviceName:'your device name which comes on adb devices in cmd'

This really worked for me.

Comment: Hello, can you show me your code please ? I don't really get it. Because if I have 2 devices which one should i put in deviceName ? should I create 2 driver (one for each device) but then it won't be parallel, it will run a test on one device then on the other

Comment: You can use the testng.xml to specify the two device names and to run them in parallel just like normal selenium grid.