# I want to make a Test Lab setup for Appium

Tags: ios, automation, appium, ios-ui-automation, appium-ios

I want to make a Test Automation Lab for Appium (Android & iOS)

Questions:
1. As per Appium limitation we can access Single device (ios) from Machine.

In this case If I connect multiple Ios/Android devices to MAC machine (Server) how I can access from other machine ?

If I make Windows machine as a server Can I access and Run scripts from MAC machine?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the selenium grid with Appium to do that. [parallel test with appium & selenium grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37485100/parallel-test-with-appium-selenium-grid/37522502#37522502)

you have to add the appium in environment variable
start the grid
start the node which you want then run in parallel

Answer (score 0):

You can go for sauce labs, Sauce Labs allows users to run tests in the cloud on more than 500 different browser platform, operating system and device combinations, providing a comprehensive test infrastructure for automated and manual testing of desktop and mobile applications using Selenium, Appium and JavaScript unit testing frameworks.

https://saucelabs.com/